# Python 3: return single Bits from a memoryview

Tags: python-3.x, bit, binary-data, memoryview

Working with python 3.5, I recieve a single byte from a PostgreSQL as memoryview.

```
>>> mybyte
<memory at 0x7fd07b12a888>
>>> bytes(mybyte)
b'\x04'
```

How can I read the single Bits of this Byte? Is there a way to get a bitwise representation of this single byte? 
I thought something like

```
>>> bin(ord(mybyte))
```

should do the trick, but it won't work on a memoryview. Also something like

```
>>> print(mybyte >> 3)
```

is clearly not working...
Thanks for any hints and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way using `binascii`:

```
In [58]: bin(int(binascii.hexlify(var), 16))
Out[58]: '0b100'
```